# Android Studio 4.1 gradle 6.7 : get manifestOutputDirectory error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

After upgrade to Android Studio 4.1, I've got the following issue when compiling :

```
> Task :app:processGoogleDebugManifest
get manifestOutputDirectory error

> Task :app:processGoogleDebugResources FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:processGoogleDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.0-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

I don't know how to solve it, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It was because of version 4.1.0
I rollback to 4.0.2 and it works :
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

Hope that they will correct it

Comment: I encountered a similar issue and going back to 4.0.2 also solved it.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172590939#comment2

Answer (score 0):

Click Android Studio->Preperences->Experimental then you have to uncheck - Only sync the active variant.

[image]