# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'. > Multiple task action failures occurred:

Tags: java, android, android-studio-4.1

My project rebuild normally but I am facing problem with release app, android min 21, max 30, 64bit lib not added android studio (4.1)
here is my dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0' // do not update it
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.3.0'

    implementation 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.4.2'
    implementation 'com.mafstech.libs:mafs-image-shape:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.2.6'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.0'
}
```

[Reference Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6ebm.png)
[Reference Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfX0b.png)

Comment: i have solved this issue ...i just roll back android studio 4.1 to 4.0.2 .. and it solved and i get ans from https://stackoverflow.com/a/64454766/14302265 ( thanks Cyrille)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 4.1 gradle 6.7 : get manifestOutputDirectory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64435636/android-studio-4-1-gradle-6-7-get-manifestoutputdirectory-error)